# Firebase Flutter Realtime Database Basic Plus Function Math

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i wanna make a Basic Plus  int1+ int2 = int3 like this one,
my first Integer is my Local TextFeld-myController , also its the Number what i wrote on the Phone.
Second Integer is my Aktuel number in Flutter RTDP ,
Third Integer is First Integer + Second Integer ,
The function working like this right now,

App run,
Admin Layout,
Get UID from a Scan QR Packet - then get Point from UID , and Get Point 2 from Point,
its actually work but if i make a Basic Plus then its showing to me a wrong result,
I got 150 Point in RTDP , and i wanna add 50 Point more to my Customer Account,
its adding 1000 Point, and Result 1150 ,
can somebody say to me why is not working this Math Function ? I tried it with num - double -int , but not worked.
Thanks.
Regards

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:********/login.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:qrscan/qrscan.dart' as scanner;

import 'Karte.dart';
import 'admin.dart';
import 'main.dart';



void punkte(String cameraScanResult) => runApp(MyApp());

var aktivpkt =FirebaseDatabase.instance
    .reference()
    .child(cameraScanResult)
    .child('Punkte/Punkte2')
    .once()
    .then((snapshot){pkt=snapshot.value;}).toString();

String pkt ="";
double data2 = 0 ;
double sayi1 = 0;
double sayi2 = 0;
double sayi3 = 0;
double sayi4 = 0;

var sa  = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(cameraScanResult).orderByChild('Punkte').orderByChild('Punkte2');
var email = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(cameraScanResult);
String as =  "" ;

final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();




  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is disposed.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Company Name"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [

            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Expanded(
                    child: new Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new StreamBuilder<Event>(
                          stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                              .reference()
                              .child(cameraScanResult)
                              .child('Punkte')
                              .onValue,
                          builder:
                              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Event> event) {
                            if (!event.hasData)
                              return new Center(child: new Text('Loading...'));
                            Map<dynamic, dynamic> data = event.data.snapshot.value;
                            return Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  //   new Text('${data['description']}',
                                  //     style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0)),
                                   // sayi2 = data['Punkte2'] ,


                                  Text('Punkte : ${data['Punkte2']}  ' ,style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,fontSize: 30,color: Colors.blueGrey),),

                                ]);
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],),),




            Text("Customer Device ID : "+ cameraScanResult),

            RaisedButton(onPressed: () async => {
              databaseReference.reference()
                  .child(cameraScanResult)
                  .child("Punkte")
                  .update({
                'Punkte2':'50'   //yes I know.
              }), },


              child: Text("Customer Validation"),
            ),

            TextField(
              controller: myController,


            ),

            RaisedButton(onPressed:() async => {

              sayi1 = double.tryParse(myController.text) * 10 ,

                 FirebaseDatabase.instance
                .reference()
                .child(cameraScanResult)
                .child('Punkte/Punkte2')
                .once()
                .then((snapshot){pkt=snapshot.value;}),

                sayi2 = double.tryParse(pkt),



              //print("Sayi1: "  + sayi1.toString()),





              sayi3 = sayi1 + sayi2,



             databaseReference.reference().child(cameraScanResult).child("Punkte").update({'Punkte2':'$sayi3'}),  //yes I know.
              Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
                print("Yeah, this line is printed after 3 seconds");
              }),
              admin(),
              setState(() {
                //cameraScanResult = null;
                sayi2 =null;
                sayi1 =null ;
                sayi3 = null ;
                sayi4 =null ;
                pkt =null ;
              }),



                 }, child: Text("Punkte Aufladen"),),






          /*  RaisedButton(onPressed:() async => {

              sayi1 = num.parse(myController.text),

              FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .reference()
                  .child(cameraScanResult)
                  .child('Punkte/Punkte2')
                  .once()
                  .then((snapshot){pkt=snapshot.value;}),
              print("Aktiv Sayi :" + pkt),

              sayi2 = num.parse(pkt),
              //print("Sayi1: "  + sayi1.toString()),

              print(sayi1.toString()),

              print("Sayi 2 :" + sayi2.toString()),

              sayi4 = (sayi2) - (sayi1),

              print ("Sayilarin Toplami :" + sayi4.toString()),

              databaseReference.reference().child(cameraScanResult).child("Punkte").update({'Punkte2':'$sayi4'     }),  //yes I know.

            },
              child: Text("Punkte Abbuchen"),

            )*/

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



punkteEkle2() {
  databaseReference.reference()
      .child(cameraScanResult)
      .child("Punkte")
      .update({
    'Punkte2':'0'   //yes I know.
  });

}







yeniSayi() {


  print("Sayi 1" + sayi1.toString());
  FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .reference()
      .child(cameraScanResult)
      .child('Punkte/Punkte2')
      .once()
      .then((snapshot){pkt=snapshot.value;});
  print("Database Sayisi :" + pkt);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are multiplying the value on that line. This is the reason for the wrong result.

```
   sayi1 = double.tryParse(myController.text) * 10, // Do not multiply!
```

Comment: Hi Akif, Berkay here ! First of all im glad to you for your Answer , but i have to calculate the points as Money ,for Example , if i type  a 10,00 € in my Controller then App must calculate that Euro => Point 10,00 mean 100 Point as Point output, 1 € is 10 Point. Do you mean that way its not going ?

Comment: Hi , i tried it that Code without that - sayi1 = double.tryParse(myController.text) * 10, // Do not multiply! ,but its still not going, its displaying another Result like 100+150 = 245 or 150+150 = 290 , have u got a another Idea ?